# Select on two attributes being different

Tags: jquery

I'd like to be able to select checkboxes where the checked value is not equal to an attribute value.

So I may have `<input type="checkbox" originalValue="false" checked="checked">`
or `<input type="checkbox" originalValue="true">` so now the user unchecked it and so it is different.

I may have a few thousand of these on a page so I just want the ones that the user has changed from their original value.  So originally the checkbox was checked, then they deselected it.

Or if it was checked, then they unchecked it, and then checked it again, then I don't want that checkbox.

Is there an elegant jQuery way to do this?

Comment: I'm quite surprised that someone with your rep has posted a question without any code to show your attempts on solving the problem?

Comment: I'm sorry but why is this too broad?  Seems pretty specific to me.  Select checkboxes where the checked value is not the same as an attribute.

Comment: When you might have many ways to code a solution, I think it can be classified as too broad, no? If you give us what you're struggling with (code) it would be easier to suggest something more narrowed down.

Comment: Not really asking for many ways, just for a single one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's always an elegant way to do things - use `filter` and filter out the opposites:

```
var changedElements = $("input:checkbox").filter(function() {
    var originalValue = $(this).attr("originalValue"); //unsure if this is auto-parsed to a bool, will have to check
    var originalBoolValue = originalValue === "true";

    return originalBoolValue != this.checked;
});
```

Comment: Thank you.  At least you understood the question